# Would an inner static runnable in a singleton block if used as wrapper for callables, if it modifies a singleton's static param?

Tags: java, singleton, runnable, callable, threadpoolexecutor

1) Is there a chance that an inner static `Runnable` class can block if it modifies a static `ConcurrentHashMap` in the outer singleton, after it calls a `Callable`?  I'm thinking about a scenario where the modification is made to the same item in the map by multiple runnables at the same time.  Multiple runnables are ran in a static `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the outer singleton.

2) Would the callable be called in the same `Thread` as the runnable, if i do a `val = myCallable.call()`?    It modifies the concurrenthashmap depending on the result of a callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ConcurrentHashMap` is designed to be non-blocking, although some contention is possible if multiple updates to the same hash segment happened simultaneously.
2. Yes.

Comment: My mistake, I am using ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is nonblocking. However, if your threads all updated the same key on the map, you will encounter contention.

Comment: I read a bit about concurrenthashmap.  It uses 32 locks on various key buckets.  So I understand your point about contention, if it's the same key.  In that case, would these threads get queued based on their arrival time?  Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

1. Except when running static initializers, Java will never implicitly block.
2. `call()` is a normal method call and will run synchronously in the calling thread, like any other method call.

Comment: I am newing the static inner class with a couple of params and passing it to the threadpoolexecutor in a for loop.  Would the runnables run concurrently?  I've written an end-to-end test testing this service, which I can modify to test if in fact the calls are concurrent or not (by introducing sleeps in my wrapped callables, and seeing if multiple runnables take the same amount of time as one of them).

Comment: @SaadShakil Whether the runnables run concurrently depends on how your executor is set up (for example, `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` will run tasks serially), but in general, assuming you're not using an exotic executor, your tasks should run concurrently.

Comment: Using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with a number of prestarted threads; not an issue. Concern is with the static inner runnable for a couple of reason: 1) Being a static inner class, would it be reused 'sequentially' in my for-loop? I am indeed newing it with a couple of params, though.  That is, its run method would execute one per pass of the loop (regardless if its newed or not), and so, the wrapped callables would be delayed in their execution.  Now that I think of it, this would also be the case if I was calling the callables in a loop. 2) Contention pointed out by @ChrisJester-Young

Comment: @SaadShakil Can you show me your code for the `run` method (and maybe the `call` method for the callable, since you mentioned it)? I can probably quickly spot if there's anything that'd block you.